# Express - How do I pass data to the model without using query string parameters

Tags: javascript, express, query-string

So, I have two controllers, `authController` and `onboardingController`. authController communicates with onboardingController with this line:

`res.redirect('/onboarding/info?profileId=' + profile.id + '&emailAddress=' + profile.emails[0].value)`

onBoardingController receives the query string parameters and transforms them into metadata that is accessible when rendering the corresponding page:

```
model.profile = { id: req.query.profileId, email: req.query.emailAddress };
res.render('onboarding/missingInfo', model);
```

Now, since `model.profile` in onboardingController doesn't know the context behind the actual profile data from the authController, I only thought of passing and receiving data through query strings. Is there any other way I can do this because having an email address in the URL makes it look wonky.

Edit: I've read that it's possible to use express sessions to do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a POST request and send it in the body of the request (using axios, or the Fetch API).

[Nice article of W3Schools about it](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)